# Duplicate paths issue

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Dash application and I got this error.
I haven't found anything on StackOverflow related to this issue.

> Exception: modules ['pages..ipynb_checkpoints.app_Km-checkpoint',
> 'pages.app_Km'] have duplicate paths

Comment: Can you give more explanation on where the error comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the dash multipage plugin? Could you provide your code and project structure?

- I have encountered a similar error myself. I am using the DASH
  multipage plugin, dash version 2.6.2
- My problem was that I was running my application from a different
  PYTHONPATH than where is my app.py - because my application structure
  looks like that for deployment purposes.
- My app structure is (simplified):

```
.
└── dash_app
    ├── app.py
    ├── callback_extensions
    │   └── login_callbacks.py
    └── pages
        ├── afterlogin.py
        ├── login.py
        └── page1.py
```

- The PYTHONPATH (path, where Python looks for modules) is set to the root directory of the project (one directory up to the `/dash_app` directory where app.py - DASH object is instantiated)

On `dash_app/pages/afterlogin.py` file, I was registering a new page:

`dash.register_page(__name__)`

- Then, I was importing one variable from the `afterlogin.py` to a different script, the `dash_app/callback_extensions/login_callbacks.py`.
- I got the following exception and the app didn't load:

`Exception: modules ['dash_app.pages.afterlogin', 'pages.afterlogin'] have duplicate paths`

**When removing the import in the `afterlogin.py` file, the problems were resolved. My guess is there exists a reference to the page app_Km.py within the .ipynb_checkpoints with a different PATH (like in my case, the module is the same but it has different referencing) that creates a 'conflict' and DASH evaluates this as a different module, when in fact it is just a reference to the same one.**

Suggestions:

- Did you try deleting the .ipynb_checkpoints altogether (are you using Jupyter notebook to run your project?)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was gone after deleting `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder or `*.py` file (in your case that `app_Km-checkpoint`) in that folder.

In JupyterLab, not only JupyterNotebook but also Python files `*.py` look like autosaved in `.ipynb_checkpoints`.